# mouse event not working -- cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Here i am binding the mouse down event of the input image.
`this.canvas` is the ID of an input image.

But nothing happens when image is pressed down.
onMouseDown function does not get called but same thing works in the HTML page.

```
 this.canvas.onmousedown = this.onMouse_Down.bind(this);
 this.canvas.onmouseup = this.onMouse_Up.bind(this);
```

Why the events are not binding  in cordova app ?

How to bind these events ?

event touch events are not working :--

```
this.canvas.touchstart = this.onMouse_Down.bind(this);
this.canvas.touchend = this.onMouse_Up.bind(this);
```

============= event listner is also not working ========

```
funtion my_func(canvasName)
{

   this.bDisabled = false;

   this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);

   // add event listner
   this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',this.onMouseDown);
   this.canvas.addEventListener('touchend',this.onMouseUp);

}

my_func.prototype.onMouseDown = function()
{
    alert('down');
    alert(this.bDisabled);
}

mY_func.prototype.onMouseUp = function()
{

    alert('up');
    alert(this.bDisabled);

}
```

why `alert(this.bdisable)`  gives output as `undefined` when input image is pressed down & up?

Comment: Is there a `mouse` event in `touch` based mobiles ? You should use `touchstart` and `touchend` events instead

Comment: even touch events are not binding .. see my edited post above

Comment: Check how to add touch events - [Link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml). If you are adding on element directly, you should use like `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend`

Comment: but mouse evnts are working in HTML app .. why same event when used as click do not work in cordova android app .. ???

Comment: see my edited post .... i even tried your method events are working with constructor function .. still one problem.. event handler is not able to access the data initialised inside myfun() ... but why alert(this.bdisable) gives output as undefined ?

Comment: Please anyone who can suggest on this ... ?

Comment: same logic is working for mousedown & mouseup events in my HTML page ..

Comment: Its working :--

 this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',this.onMouseDown.bind(this));

This is how to do it...!!